# Bitwise and condition in a Laravel relation (Eloquent ORM)

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to create a specialized relation on a user (Model) to the group model. In the schema I am working with, the groups have a type attribute that is a bitmask, where each bit defines a certain characteristic for a group.

For example, we might have a group:

```
name: New York
type: 33554436 (1<<25 | 1<<24)
```

With plain SQL, I can get the groups of interest in with the query:

```SQL
select g.* from foobar_group g  where (type & 1<<25) != 0
```

I wish to define this relation in the user model for convenience and what have is:

```
<?php

class UserModel extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{

    public function visitedCities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            GroupModel::class,
            'foobar_group_member',
            'user_id',
            'group_id')
          ->with([ 'type' => function ($belongsToMany) {
              $belongsToMany->where('type', '&', 
                    GroupModel::CITY_TYPE,
                    GroupModel::CITY_TYPE)
          }])
        ;
    }
}
```

In essence, I am trying to add the where condition from the SQL query above to the join statement (relation). Do you know how to do that? Do I need to extend the Eloquent\Relation class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `whereRaw`to execute raw where clauses.

Eloquent doesn't support more fancy where clauses than `like` or `=` and the standard stuff. I suggest you take a look at [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

I your case you probably want to use the something like:

```
$belongsToMany->whereRaw('(type & 1<<25) != 0')
```

and add it to your select clause.

If you want to debug your SQL you can use:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
//Execute Eloquent select
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

That way you can also see that if you put anything like bitmasks into the middlepart of the where clause it gets replaced with `=`